# What does "from updates excluded (updateinfo)" mean on "yum check-update --security"

Tags: linux, security, centos, updates, yum

I've got an CentOS 7.3 installation running with automated security updates. Sometimes i check if there are available security updates. I noticed that many updates are excluded.

The function i ran is "yum check-update --security".
I get a list of all the updates with for example this line:
kernel-debug-devel-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 from updates excluded (updateinfo)

Can someone tell me what this exaclty means.
I'm confused because security updates for the kernel should always be installed.

Answer (score 2):

Happened upon this looking for some other information. Although Yum is capable of handling update notifications via [`updateinfo.xml`](http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.6/x86_64/os/repodata/updateinfo.xml), the CentOS project does not publish that file. No updates available from the official repositories will show up within Yum as security-related.

There's a few workarounds if you truly need update classifications. The most straightforward is to simply use a [mirror that distributes `updateinfo.xml`](https://updateinfo.cefs.steve-meier.de/). Alternately you can [generate that information yourself](https://github.com/vmfarms/generate_updateinfo) and use [a mirror of your own](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror) that includes it. It's also possible to copy the update information from Red Hat directly and do some text replacement into your own `updateinfo.xml`

There's a few other approaches that don't involve using Yum's security plugin/feature. [This post](https://petersouter.xyz/the-story-of-errata-for-centos/) does an excellent job of covering them.